# Cannot generate a new Machine Learning Entity Model in Watson Knowledge Studio

Tags: ibm-watson, watson

Starting a few days ago I've been having issues deploying any new custom entity model in Watson Knowledge Studio.
I have updated the model ID in the passed object.
The deployment status (under the Machine Learning Version page) is stuck on "starting" and my curl call is returning "model temporarily unavailable".

$ curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -u "username":"password" -d @C:/Users/Pedro/Desktop/parameters.json https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/natural-language-understanding/api/v1/analyze?version=2017-02-27
  "language": "en",
  "error": "model temporarily not available",
  "code": 500
}

To fix it, I have tried deleting all other Machine Leaning Model versions (in case of space limitations), re-annotated, and re-trained the model to no avail.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there was a temporary issue, which has been fixed. Please try again, it should be working fine now.